# How to level up your World in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I leveled up my Mechromancer in Borderlands 2 with Gibbed Borderlands 2 Save Editor, but I only see Level 36 enemies that drop Level 36 items. How I can change the World Level with the program?

Comment: I thought enemies levelled based on the player, perhaps you're in an area where the enemy level cap is low?

Comment: Have you tried leveling up normally for 1 level to see if it updates the enemies?  Not sure if this is the answer, but just curious if you have tried.

Comment: Are you playing the game for the second time? I think the first playthrough is capped. So you might need to defeat jack, and start a second playthrough (that one has a special name, I can't recall it atm).

Comment: The first playthrough has enemies from level 1 to 30-something. The second one has from said 30-something all the way to 50. The THIRD playthrough - Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode - is the one that has enemies who scale to your leve.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not familiar with this tool that you've used, I assume you were in your first playthrough. During the first playthrough, enemies only get up to around level 35. Once you've finished that playthrough by

> killing The Warrior

You will unlock the next playthrough, True Vault Hunter Mode. During this playthrough, enemies start at approximately level 34 and go all the way up to level 50. Once the playthrough is completed, all enemies will be level 50. [The Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/True_Vault_Hunter_Mode) highlights other ways enemies are different besides level (summarised by me):

> - Increased Enemy Health
> - More Badasses
> - New Enemies
> - Better Loot
> - More XP from missions

In both of these modes, enemy level is based on the zone that you're in.

Once you complete this mode (in the same manner as the first), you will unlock a third playthrough: Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode. In this playthrough, enemies just scale to the highest level in the party (during solo this will be your level). The enemies always scale to the level of the highest party member, regardless of area that you are in (unlike the other two modes).

The reason you are only seeing enemies up to level 36 is because you are probably in the first playthrough still. You will need to play through the main story, and complete this playthrough to unlock subsequent playthroughs where enemies and loot will be higher.